# VSTS Tests not running

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, build-server

I have got an issue on the test step on the VSTS build where our tests are unable to run.

The following link is the [build steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmuCt.png).

On the test step on the build i get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Kv7.png):

**2018-04-17T06:11:35.6527068Z ##[error]Error: An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Type is not resolved for member 'Sfa.Sfs.AgeReports.Contexts.AgeReportDefaultAgeReportDomainFactory,Sfa.Sfs.AgeReports.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
2018-04-17T06:11:35.6527068Z ##[error]**

All tests run locally on multiple dev machines but on VSTS they don't run.

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: Looks like one of your projects is missing a reference required for other dependency.

Comment: @yoger wouldn't that mean that the tests shouldn't work locally?

Comment: do your build agent machine have .net (and correct version) installed?

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? Is there restore package task (e.g. NuGet restore)? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive (Set system.debug variable to true and queue build, then share this log)?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Sharing log on OneDrive is not a good idea. If the question cannot be clearly formulated and self-contained it's not suitable for SO.

Comment: @jocke yes they do.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I have attached all of our build steps.

Comment: What's the result if you run the test by calling [VSTest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) command manually on your build agent machine?